# Is it possible to develop plugins for Google Talk client?

Tags: plugins, google-talk

I saw the Google Talk Always Idle plugin [http://www.nirmaltv.com/2007/10/29/make-your-gtalk-status-always-idle/ ] and got interested in the possibility of developing similar plugins for the gtalk client. Is it possible to develop plugins for gtalk? I have searched extensively and haven't found a thing in this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create plugins for gtalk.  They use the XMPP protocol, and there are several sites on it.  You can start here:

http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html